# FindLast on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ilist

I would like to call `FindLast` on a collection which implements `IEnumerable`, but `FindLast` is only available for `List`.  What is the best solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent to:

```
var last = list.FindLast(predicate);
```

is

```
var last = sequence.Where(predicate).LastOrDefault();
```

(The latter will have to check *all* items in the sequence, however...)

Effectively the "Where()" is the Find part, and the "Last()" is the Last part of "FindLast" respectively. Similarly, `FindFirst(predicate)` would be map to `sequence.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()` and `FindAll(predicate)` would be `sequence.Where(predicate)`.

Comment: Depending on the comparison method, length of list and frequency of matches it might be more CPU efficient to:
sequence.Reverse.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();

Not very memory efficient however.

Answer (score 5):

How about with LINQ-to-Objects:

```
var item = data.LastOrDefault(x=>x.Whatever == "abc"); // etc
```

If you only have C# 2, you can use a utility method instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        int lastOdd = SequenceUtil.Last<int>(
            data, delegate(int i) { return (i % 2) == 1; });
    }    
}
static class SequenceUtil {
    public static T Last<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        T last = default(T);
        foreach (T item in data) {
            if (predicate(item)) last = item;
        }
        return last;
    }
}
```

Comment: The top bit, maybe - but I thought the 2.0 stuff might be useful, so I kept it separate.

Comment: Ah, only saw v1!

Handn't even considered that one would go and invest the time to expand on it as you did...

BTW for all these Util type things, PowerCollections used to be my hammer back when I was constrained to 2.0 - algorithms.cs is a great read. Bet it's Last() has an opt for Collection!

Answer (score 1):

you can add you collection to a new List by passing it to List<> constructor.

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>(MyCol);
myList.FindLast....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension method Last()
which is located in the namespace System.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is invalid because a collection has no last element. A more specialized collection that does have a complete ordering is a list. A more specialized collection that does not have an ordering is a dictionary.